# How to loop through an array in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

i'm trying to loop through an array, I have two input values and I am trying to get one value to print in val1 and the second value in val2.So I had to make a text file called test_inputs.txt which has all the inputs that I need to print

This is the text file
test_inputs.txt

```
1,2
3,4
10,30
```

I already know how to put the inputs in the array but I am having trouble printing the values.
So far I have this

```
//this reads the text file and puts it in an array
IFS=,$'\n' read -d '' -r -a array < test_inputs.txt

for i in "${array[@]}"
do 
echo "val1: ${array[$i}} and val2: ${array[$i++]}"
done
```

The desired output is

```
val1: 1 and val2: 2
val1: 3 and val2: 4
val1: 10 and val2: 30
```

Comment: With your loop, `i` takes successive **elements** of the array.  You want to use **indexes** into the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a C-style `for` loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=,$'\n' read -d '' -r -a array < test_inputs.txt
n=${#array[*]}
for ((i = 0; i < n; i += 2))
do 
    echo "val1: ${array[i]} and val2: ${array[i+1]}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question in that each line contains 2 entries, separated by a comma.

I suggest in this case to read the array line by line, instead by element:

```
mapfile <test_inputs.txt
for line in "${MAPFILE[@]}"
do
  echo "val1: ${line%,*} and val2: ${line#*,}"
done
```